# Raspberry Pi/OBDII/Serial Communications over Bluetooth

Tags: linux, python, bluetooth

Thanks for having a look at my post and my problem :)

I'm presently developing an automotive on-board diagnostics scanner application in python3/wxPython. For the communications heavy lifting, I'm using the python-obd library, found at https://github.com/brendan-w/python-OBD/releases

This work is taking place on a raspberry pi 3 model b+ and a Veepeak OBD-II obd port interface. This interface is a Bluetooth device which is accessed via a virtual serial port on the Pi.

So far I've been testing on my old '98 Toyota truck; what I'm seeing is that the 'OK" response stops when the ATE0 command is sent. This is reflected both in the debug logs of the python obd library I'm using, and in my experiences working interactively with the Veepeak via the Minicom terminal program.

This prevents the library code from responding sensibly, as a casual reading of the relevant source fragments in the repository illustrates a dependency on the 'OK' response during initialization of the elm327 for communications.

Though more vigorous testing would certainly be helpful, so far my wife's late-model Nissan Rogue exhibits similar behaviour.

Has anyone else seen this sort of behaviour after an ate0 command?

AFAICT from the connected wiring on the port, the truck is using either SAE J1850 VPW (10.4 kbaud) or ISO 9141-2 (5 baud init, 10.4 kbaud). Dunno about the wife's Rogue.

If it is the latter, running the initialization at 10.4kbaud could be less than constructive...

Comment: I'd like to say the decision to move this post here was pedantic and ill conceived. Any reading of the post past the words 'raspberry pi' would have shown that the post is topically centered on the obd2 standard of automotive diagnostic technology, and concerns a solution that can deployed with no modification to any platform worth consideration.

Never mind that though, raspberry pi is mentioned, so lets put it over here where it doesn't offend anyone's categorization OCD.

Too bad it wont have visibility there with it's intended audience.

Major fail. Thanks for naught.